# Using python to export from pardot when pypardots won't do

Tags: rest-api, data-export, pardot

I finally got authentication to work and I can get the access token and the reset token which I knwo got pypardotsf to work.  However pypardot doesn't seem to support export.  So, I tried it au naturel like this:

```
uri = f'https://pi.pardot.com/api/export/version/4/do/create'
params = {
    "object": 'visitorActivity',
    #"fields": [string, string, ....],
    "procedure": {
        "name": 'filter_by_created_at',
        "arguments": {
            "created_after": "2020-09-30 10:00:00",
            "created_before": "2021-09-30 24:59:59"
        }
    }
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
'Pardot-Business-Unit-Id': business_unit_id}
x = requests.post(uri, headers = headers, data = params)
```

as only visitorActivity seems to work with the export API.  A pity since it lists so many other objects for no reason then.  Anyway, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<rsp stat="fail" version="1.0">\n   <err code="46">This API user lacks sufficient permissions for the requested operation</err>\n</rsp>\n
```

I have the full api privilege.  Does this mean my entire attempt to access pardot failed or that I succeeded but there is yet another setting I need to click to get the access to export this object.  I can read 200 records at a time with pypardotsf, but if there are a million visits, that's 50k calls before I can get all the data.  Not the greatest.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe how you granted "full API privilege" to your user.

Comment: I solved it.  It turns out there's an export view you also need.